# Identification of SOT-23 device

Tags: power-electronics, identification

I have a small SOT-23 (3 pins, transistor-like) device that burned out (shorted between 2 pins). I need to identify it so i can replace it.

It belongs to an Asus mainboard and after it burned down the SSD1 interface (on the left) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGRl6.png) stopped working (no damage to the HDD).

The marking on it seems to be 018 ⊃

Any help would be apreciated.

[image: The burned component]

[image: the area around it]

[image: desoldered and pin tensions]

Comment: Can you remove that component and then use your multi-meter to tell us what voltage each pin has? (aka where is each pin connected. To 5V? GND?)

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios How would you be able to tell that? Pins don't have voltage when removed from a circuit, you can tell resistance and which may be connected together, but I'm not sure how you can identify which is GND and Supply...?

Comment: I meant the pins on the PCB, not on the component. Remove the component, and measure the voltage on the PCB.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I cannot desolder it right now
I've been looking at some similar mainboard schematics and it could be a N-MOSFET 2N7002K
I't a common SOT-23 around that area

Comment: It probably is either a mosfet or a BJT transistor, its base being the right pin, and the top and bottom left the source and drain

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I desoldered it and added the photo of tensions betwen pins.
3.27 between the bottom ones, 1.27 between top and bottom left, 1.80 or less between bottom right and top

Comment: [APR3001-17A](http://www.datasheetq.com/datasheet-download/287020/1/Anpec/APR3001-17A) is a possibility with those markings. Pinout is plausible with PCB layout. 1.80V correlates with the 1.75V of the 'B' device.

Answer (score 0):

The marking is "01B" in fact if you zoom more and the marking format is typical from Onsemi (dot below and sideways character for traceability).

Then this is probably a LP2301BLT1G / T3G from Leshan Radio Company (Onsemi and LRC are associated in China ([source](https://www.onsemi.com/company/news-media/press-announcements/en/on-semiconductor-s-joint-manufacturing-venture-ranked-among-china-s-top-10-semiconductor-assembly-and-test-enterprises)) ).

[LP2301BLT1G datasheet](https://bomyg.com/images/guigeshu/LRC/LP2301BLT1G.pdf)

[image]

Picture from [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFET_LRC-LP2301BLT1G_C55450.html):
[image]